# Why json_decode doesn't work for me?

Tags: php, json

I'm a little confused here. if I pass a variable to json_decode, it doesn't work:

```
$stringJSON = $_GET['jsonstring'];  
echo $stringJSON;
$stringObject = json_decode($stringJSON);
var_export($stringObject);
```

The first echo correctly shows me the JSON string I passed, e.g.

```
{\"Items\":[{\"Name\":\"name\",\"Description\":\"\"],\"Name\":\"Christmas\"}
```

The second echo shows NULL.
So I grab the string from the first echo and write the following code:

```
$stringObject = json_decode("{\"Items\":[{\"Name\":\"name\",\"Description\":\"\"],\"Name\":\"Christmas\"}");
var_export ($stringObject);
```

And what do you say, it shows me the correctly decoded array. The string is absolutely the same, I even kept the escape characters. Or maybe they are the problem?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like your server has `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled. Either [disable it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) or run `$stringJSON` through `stripslashes()` before using it.

```
$stringJSON = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ?
    stripslashes($_GET['jsonstring']) : $_GET['jsonstring'];
```

Comment: It will break content if it contains UTF encoded text as it will be removed too

Comment: @aokaddaoc you are right of course. The best option is to disable magic quotes

Answer (score 5):

This

```
[{\"Name\":\"name\",\"Description\":\"\"]
```

needs to be

```
[{\"Name\":\"name\",\"Description\":\"\"}]
```

You are missing the closing `}`

Answer (score 2):

If it shows you a string with slashes in it when you `echo` it, that means the string has slashes in it. That's not a valid JSON string, the slashes don't belong there. If you paste that string into PHP, the slashes are evaluated by PHP. The string literal `"\""` in PHP source code evaluates to the string `"`, so the slashes are effectively removed and you are decoding a valid JSON string.

I suspect you have [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) on which are inserting the slashes into GET values, turn them off.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quoting problem: Try the following

```
$stringObject = json_decode("{\"Items\":[{\"Name\":\"name\",\"Description\":\"\"],\"Name\":\"Christmas\"}");
echo $stringObject;
var_export ($stringObject);
```

as you see, the $stringObject has no quotes (but the one coming from $_GET has them)

so you might need

```
$stringJSON = $_GET['jsonstring'];  
$stringObject = json_decode(stripslashes($stringJSON));
var_export($stringObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

run json_decode twice.

```
$str = json_decode($jsonData,true);
$str = json_decode($str,true);
```

It may help someone.

Comment: I dunno why... But it DOES WORK for me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

it may help you.