# How to pass an multidimensional JS array with Post Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, multidimensional-array

i have a problem with JS multidimensional array and ajax, im tried many things and decide to make a join of the array to then, make a explode on php and get the array.

I decide that after look that if a send the "park" array just like that:

```
    $.post( VIEW+THEME+"ajax/insertPark.php", {
            p:Base64.encode(park),
    }
```

I dont get the array on PHP.

Join doesnt works fine,i dont know if is because me array dont looks like: [fruit,food,meat]...

And in the console.log test the park.join make that park be the string '~', with no other data.

```
var park = [];
    $.each(languajes, function(i, itemData) {
        park[i] = [];
        park[i]['idLanguaje']   = itemData['idLanguaje'];
        park[i]['name'] = $('#name-'+itemData['idLanguaje']).val();
    });

    console.log(park);
    console.log(park.join('~'));

    $.post( VIEW+THEME+"ajax/insertPark.php", {
            p:Base64.encode(park.join('~')),
    }, function(data) {
        //window.location.href='/';
    }, "json" );
```

Any idea how i can do this? The elements on the array depends of the number of languajes on database, (i.e.: the name of a park on diferents languajes), can be ES,EN or ES,EN,RU,FR... and function must adapt to this.

Thanks in advice !

Comment: your `park` variable isn't a multi-dimensional array, it's an array of objects. Change the line `park[i] = []` to `park[i] = {};` to reflect that, also: try sending the data as a JSON string: `JSON.stringify(park);`

Comment: Yah, thank u too much, i was thinking maybe i had something bad in that line, but dont know {} to define 2nd dimension on the array.

Comment: the `{}` doesn't define a second dimension, it defines an _object_: JS doesn't have associative arrays, only arrays with numeric indexes or objects (in fact, arrays are just _"pimped"_ objects, too). It's pretty much like C(++): an array: `int intArray[];` vs `struct assocArray { int foo; char *bar;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make json from your array and stringify it - [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

In PHP use json_decode function

Comment: Is neccesary to download the library? or is native now?

Comment: it is native for IE 8 + and other modern brosers

Answer (score 2):

You could try encoding your array into JSON? Something like this?

JS:

```
var parkString = JSON.stringify(park);
$.post( VIEW+THEME+"ajax/insertPark.php", {
        p: parkString,
}
```

PHP:

```
$park = json_decode($_POST['p'], true);
```

Comment: Now i have the data on $_REQUEST['p'] or $_POST['p'] in PHP but the json_decode doesnt works :S.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904764/why-json-decode-doesnt-work-for-me, solution found here